# How do I specify max screen size in Android Manifest to be 5 inches?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support

I want to restrict my app to devices that screen is bigger than 5 inches. I have this code, but it seems that works for 4.7 inches:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="536" />
```

Can you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: dont you mean you want the Minimum screen size to be 5"?

Comment: @tyczj no, I need the max size to be 5"

Comment: `I want to restrict my app to devices that screen is bigger than 5 inches` makes no sense then and what you are checking for is everything above a small screen size which would mean you want a minimum screen size of 5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how android divide the screen ranges, I don't think you can specify more than that.

[image: screen range]